# Android Phonegap and Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova, android-fragments

Im trying to implement a Phonegap CordovaWebView into my Fragment, but it doesn't work.

My Layout looks like the following (cordovawebview.xml):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id = "@+id/mainView"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

In My Fragment's `onCreateView()` I try to inflate the layout:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cordovawebview, container); // <--- the error occurs here!
    // CordovaWebView webView = (CordovaWebView)v.findViewById(R.id.mainView);

    return v;
}
```

Maybe someone has some hints how to fix it. I always get that error:

```
10-25 15:52:02.839: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at com.advantageframework.tabs.fragments.SampleFragmentA.onCreateView(SampleFragmentA.java:81)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    ... 19 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadConfiguration(CordovaWebView.java:643)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.<init>(CordovaWebView.java:131)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Did you figure out the problem yet? Just having the same problem and started investigating.

Comment: unfortunately not. i'm now using activities along with CordovaInterface. if you need an entrypoint for this just try out https://github.com/infil00p/CordovaActionView. In MainActivity you can change "MainActivity extends ActionBarAvtivity" to "MainActivity extends FragmentActivity" or SherlockFragmentActivity if you need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer. If you look in your logcat you see, that it tries to cast the Context to CordovaInterface. The context is the Activity. There it fails. You probably made the Fragment be CordovaInterface. That is what I did. You will have to make the Activity a CordovaInterface and from the Activity forward the events (onMessage, ...) to the Fragment.

Here is my activity (with some stuff removed to make it simpler). I have something very close to this that works pretty well. You will still experience some smaller problems afterwards, but those are easy to solve.

```
public class MyCordovaActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
        CordovaInterface {
    private final ExecutorService mThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private CordovaPlugin mActivityResultCallback;

    private CordovaFragment mFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nbu_web_activity);
        mFragment = new CordovaFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment, mFragment)
                .commit();

        // TODO this value you could pass to the activity with a intent extra
        // or allow to do this through a seperate function, ...
        String url = "http://....";
        mFragment.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        NBUGapFragment fragment = getCordovaFragment();
        if (fragment != null && fragment.appView != null) {
            fragment.appView.onNewIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        NBUGapFragment fragment = getCordovaFragment();
        if (fragment == null || !fragment.onBackPressed()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelLoadUrl() {
        getCordovaFragment().cancelLoadUrl();
    }

    @Override
    public Activity getActivity() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Context getContext() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
        return mThreadPool;
    }

    @Override
    public Object onMessage(final String id, final Object data) {
        return getCordovaFragment().onMessage(id, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void setActivityResultCallback(final CordovaPlugin plugin) {
        mActivityResultCallback = plugin;
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(final CordovaPlugin plugin, final Intent intent,
            final int requestCode) {
        mActivityResultCallback = plugin;
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
        if (mActivityResultCallback != null) {
            mActivityResultCallback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }
    }

    private CordovaFragment getCordovaFragment() {
        // the CordovaFragment is the one implementing CordovaInterface
        return mFragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a naked code construct? just to be sure - that would be awesome!

Comment: can you also share the Code of your CordovaFragment ??
I was trying to build it but I think Im stuck about returning Activity from getActivity() method within fragment If I implement Cordova Interface.

Comment: @osayilgan: not sure i understand your problem. basically you implement the fragment similar to this: https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/DroidGap.java

Comment: @PatrickBoos I know this class, I also use it when I want to use CordovaWebView within my activities. The thing that I'm basically asking is, this DroidGap class is extended from Activity, not Fragment. In the case you want to implement CordovaInterface within fragment, then you need to implement getActivity() method which is also a super class from FragmentActivity.

Comment: As far as I see, you have a class called CordovaFragment in the code above, and do you also implement CordovaInterface within this Fragment ? If you implement it, can you share it here ? Because I tried to do something similar and I get an error whenever I finish the FragmentActivity, It says that I need to unregister the receiver. But I didnt have any receiver within Fragment or FragmentActivity.

Comment: Sadly I can not share all the code of the fragment. Too much in there that I would have to take out. But as a note. The error you see is from the WebView (if I remember correctly). I remember having that one too, but do not totally remember how I solved it. Just try to track down the error in the CordovaWebView (i think that is where it came from).

Comment: As a side note. The more I do cordova with fragments, the more I start disliking cordova. It is totally built for mainly be used in Activities and not in Fragments. You will end up with TONS of problems. This problem right now won't be your last ;-). But it is doable. But a lot of work.

Comment: I have to use CordovaInterface in one of my project, as you said it seems like there is something wrong with FragmentActivity. Because it works totally good with Activity but not FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 2):

CordovaWebView assumes Inflater's context (in this case, main Activity) implements CordovaInterface. There's no interface pass separate object (context and CordovaInterface object) through inflater, you should create proxy context which contain two object and delegate method call to each;

```
private class CordovaContext extends ContextWrapper implements CordovaInterface
{
    CordovaInterface ci;

    // Hold two objects. Method call to Context will be proxied by ContextWrapper, so only delegate CordovaInterface.
    // You should add/modify when method in CordovaInterface changed
    public CordovaContext(Context base, CordovaInterface ci) {
        super(base);
        this.ci = ci;
    }
    public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin command,
            Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        ci.startActivityForResult(command, intent, requestCode);
    }
    public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin plugin) {
        ci.setActivityResultCallback(plugin);
    }
    public Activity getActivity() {
        return ci.getActivity();
    }
    public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) {
        return ci.onMessage(id, data);
    }
    public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
        return ci.getThreadPool();
    }

}
```

In Fragment, create inflater which uses this Context object;

```
LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(new CordovaContext(getActivity(), this));
View v = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.cordovawebview, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cordovawebview, container, false); // <--- add false parameter
    CordovaWebView webView = (CordovaWebView)v.findViewById(R.id.mainView);

    return v;
}
```